# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8631, 28), indices imply (8631, 17)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pipe

- step1: pipeline is created
- step2: convert pipleine to dataframe
- step3: I am trying convert pipeline to data frame but exception is raised. how to solve this problem
- step4: how to solve ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8631, 28), indices imply (8631, 17) on top of pipeline conversion to dataframe,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

print("step1: import lib")
print("step2: loading raw data")
df = pd.read_csv("online_shoppers_intention.csv")

print("step3: data preparition")
X = df.drop(['Revenue'], axis = 1)
y = df['Revenue']

print("step4: data splitting")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .3, random_state = 0)
names = X_train.columns.tolist()

numeric_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'constant')
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')

numerical_cols = X.select_dtypes(exclude = "object").columns.values.tolist()
categorical_cols = X.select_dtypes(exclude = ['int', 'float64', 'bool']).columns.values.tolist()
    
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, numerical_cols)
    ,('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ],
    remainder = 'passthrough')

pipe_preprocessor = Pipeline(steps = [("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("pandarizer", FunctionTransformer(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x, columns = names)))]).fit(X_train)
    
X_train_pipe = pipe_preprocessor.transform(X_train)
X_test_pipe = pipe_preprocessor.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in part of your code `pd.DataFrame(x, columns = names)` because in previous step you preprocess the categorical columns with `categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')`, it increases the number of columns that's why shapes mismatch, as a solution you can try to change OneHotEncoder with LabelEncoder or change `names` list according new numbers of columns